# How to use python with docker globally?

Tags: python, bash, docker, shell

I wrote a little script

```sh
#!/bin/bash

docker run -it --rm --name my-running-script -v "$PWD":/usr/src/myapp -w /usr/src/myapp python:3 $(realpath $1)
```

With this I want to be able to call scripts like `python3 myscript.py`

However I get the error

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:367: starting container process caused: exec: "/absolute/path/to/file.py": stat /absolute/path/to/file.py: no such file or directory: unknown.
```

So I tried creating an alias in my `.bashrc`

```sh
alias python3='docker run -it --rm --name my-running-script -v "$PWD":/usr/src/myapp -w /usr/src/myapp python:3'
```

Here I get the following error

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:367: starting container process caused: exec: "myscript.py": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.
```

I'm by far no bash expert, but what could be the reason for this error? What did I do wrong?

Comment: That sounds like you want to use Python directly, not via an isolated Docker container.  Are you on a native Linux or MacOS host; does it already have a Python installed that you can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In bash the solution would be

```sh
#!/bin/bash

docker run -it --rm --name my-running-script --entrypoint python -v "$PWD":/usr/src/myapp -w /usr/src/myapp python:3 $1
```

usage: `python3 myscript.py`

as alias in my `.bashrc`

```
alias run_py3='docker run -it --rm --name my-running-script --entrypoint python -v "$PWD":/usr/src/myapp -w /usr/src/myapp python:3'
```

usage: `run_py3 myscript.py`

For the alias I couldn't use "python3" because the name is already taken on my system.